# What is the maximum crypto map sequence number in IOS-XE?

Tags: vpn

What is the maximum sequence number you can use in crypto map with IOS-XE?

Or to ask a slightly different question, how many sequences can you have in a crypto map?

I can't find any limits in the command reference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

65535? This is a csr1000v and what it said was:

[image]
[image]